# How can i create multiple function's in Selenium+C# for a single Login page test cases

Tags: c#, asp.net, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

For example:- 
I have a Login page with Username and password. and their 10 test cases in my mind so how can I write my script using the function for this 10 test cases.

Answer (score 1):

You should opt for **Data driven testing.**

**Why :**

There are a number of data sets that we have to run the same tests on. And, to create a different test for each data set values is time-consuming and inefficient.

**Data Driven Testing** overcomes this issue by keeping the data external to Functional tests and loading them when there is a need to extend the automation tests.

Use of **TestNG** :

1. TestNG is a framework that makes Data Driven automation Testing possible in Selenium.
2. It has some additional key features such as parameterization, parallel test execution etc

Here is a full **Implementation** of **Data** **driven** **testing**.

I have used **gmail** for that (**With 5 set of test data**):

```
public class Sumit{

    WebDriver driver;
    WebDriverWait wait;

    @BeforeMethod
    public void setUpClass(){
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "F:\\Automation\\chromedriver.exe");
        driver = new ChromeDriver();
        wait = new WebDriverWait(driver,30); 
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        driver.get("https://www.google.com/");
    }

    @Test(dataProvider="testdata")
    public void testLogin(String userName,String password) throws Exception {
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//a[text()='Sign in']")));
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[text()='Sign in']")).click();
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@aria-label='Email or phone']")).sendKeys(userName);
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//span[text()='Next']/ancestor::div[@id='identifierNext']")));
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[text()='Next']/ancestor::div[@id='identifierNext']")).click();
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@aria-label='Enter your password']")).sendKeys(password);
        Thread.sleep(2000);
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[text()='Next']/ancestor::div[@id='passwordNext']")).click();
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//div[contains(text(),'Wrong password. Try again or click Forgot password to reset it.')]")));
        String errorText = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[contains(text(),'Wrong password. Try again or click Forgot password to reset it.')]")).getText();
        System.out.println(errorText);
    }

    @DataProvider(name = "testdata")
    public Object[][] gmailData() {
     return new Object[][] {
       { "abc123@gmail.com", "yourpassowrd"},
       { "abc1234@gmail.com", "yourpassowrd"},
       {"abc12345@gmail.com","yourpassowrd"},
       {"abc12346@gmail.com","yourpassowrd"},
       {"abc12347@gmail.com","yourpassowrd"},
     };
    }


    @AfterMethod
    public void tearDown() throws Exception {
        Thread.sleep(3000);
        driver.close();   
      } 
}
```

**P.S** : 1. I'm not good in C# , that's why I have written code in Java, same you can mapped to C#.

2. For more reference you can go through **TestNG** documentation :  [TestNG Documentation](http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html)
3. You can use CSV files , Excel files and Data Bases for Data Driven Testing , However the solution provided by me do not use any one of these.